# mod_rewrite rule to remove #! from URL?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am building a javascript application with ajax loads, and incase any user visits a URL with a hashbang in it, I want to rewrite the URL and remove it. I am not very familiar with mod_rewrite, but I gave this a shot:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^#! [NC] 
RewriteRule ^#!/(.*)$ http://mysite.com/$1 [R=301]
```

I even tried escaping the special characters by using `\#\!` in both the places, but somehow I getting some weird erractic redirects.
Any mod_rewrite experts out there?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fragment of a URI is only for local use and is not part of the request to the server and thus not available on the server side. So you can’t remove it with mod_rewrite or any other server side technique.

Comment: Hmm. I was afraid of this.. So the fragment part is completely inaccessible to mod_rewrite?

Comment: @Munim: Yes, the fragment will not be part of the requested URI.